# Does flurry still be supported in CN1?

Tags: codenameone

I installed the flurry extension and sent my app to the cn1 iOS App store build.

Failed to build it with the errors:

```
/Objects-normal/armv7/native_com_codename1_flurry_FlurryNativeImplCodenameOne.o native_com_codename1_flurry_FlurryNativeImplCodenameOne.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

Comment: It's an old project last updated in 2017 but it might be a simple fix. We'll need the full error log to determine the problem.

Comment: Could I send the error log to CN1 chat?

Comment: The "armv7" is suspicious.  Are you using any build hints that cause it to target armv7?  It is likely that the latest Flurry sdk, which is linked to the latest version in cocoapods, doesn't support armv7 anymore.

Comment: I don't know. What are the build hints related to armv7?
I use the Ant version of cn1 to compile my app.

Comment: You can add the log to the chat. Look in the build hints section in Codename One Settings. Which dependencies do you have other than flurry? Maybe one of them added the problematic build hint.

Comment: I uploaded the error log file and the screenshot of my build hints in Codename One Settings to the chat.

Comment: What is the status of this build error issue? Anyon can help?